# Tracking of registered mobile users/associates who are in defined radius of distance

Tags: android

I have registered users on mobile who can be tracked on maps, once they have their mobile active with the apps. I want to track only the users who are available in a close proximity of about 1 KM (which can be defined). 
As of now, I get result of all registered users irrespective of their distance. can you help how to track the users within the radius of choice and also users coming into that radius.

Thanks

Comment: are you storing the user data somewhere like a SQL database on a platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all users' location (longitude and latitude).
Then calculate all users distance between each other on setting time.
([track distance and time based on my track details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266589/track-distance-and-time-based-on-my-track-details) )

Then you will know who is coming someone else radius.